# Add additional field to a Task form. The Task is generated using an OOTB Disposition Workflow

Tags: custom-form, tasks, task-list, information-management

I need to **add an additional field to a Task form page**.  The SP Settings cog does not give the option to 'edit page', so I think I need to do this in Designer.

I have a document management system set up.  When the date criteria is satisfied,  e.g. if [Modified Date] is 1 year ago, generate a task to review the document.  The task is generated by an OOTB Disposition workflow.

The trouble is a task only shows the file name, but not the List name, I need the List name to show here or else a url which indicates the List name.  Multiple document libraries will add new tasks to the Document Disposition Task List, so the originating list needs to be distinguishable.

One other thing, when I right click on the link to the file name and select 'Properties', there is am Address (URL) which shows the originating Document Library.

**Updated - added picture**:

This url displays the disposition task (see the picture below - this is the url of the picture).

```
https://intranet.mycompanyname.com/uk/quality/_layouts/15/WrkTaskIP.aspx?List=[List ID of the Disposition Task List aka GUID] &ID=12&Source=https%3A%2F%2Fintranet%2Emycompanyname%2Ecom%2Fuk%5F%2Fquality%2FLists%2FDisposition%5FExpired%5FDoc%5FMgment%2520Tasks%2FAllItems%2Easpx&ContentTypeId=combinationofalphanumeric
```

[image: no link to the source doc library, where the document is stored]

Additional info:

If you are not familiar with the Disposition Workflow, [this post explains the premise](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/disposition-approval-workflow-in-sharepoint-2013/).

Comment: Hi folks - any suggestions at all on this one?  Is it possible to edit the form in Designer somehow?

Comment: Note to self, see if this can help: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepointdesigner/2012/09/14/how-to-manipulate-the-task-form-with-sharepoint-designer-for-new-task-actions/